# GSON Only parsing object name

Tags: java, json, object, key

I'm trying to parse JSON with GSON and I think I'm getting the hang of it.  The problem I have is it seems to stop parsing after the object name.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json = "{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\"}";
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    map=(Map<String,String>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
}
```

Works fine and outputs:

[k1, k2]

And I can use those keys to get the values fine which is what I want to do.

If I use the same code with this JSON Object from json.org

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only output I get is

[glossary]

I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing, can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: The second JSON object is rather complex. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Your second object has exactly one key (`glossary`) and one value for that key (the object containing all the other stuff).

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is get the values without knowing the names of the keys.  So using the second json example from above I would want to be able to do something like this *pseudo-code*

I thought I would be able to break down that JSON object by each level programmaticly showing the value of title, then ID, etc with some sort of loop. 

for(int i=0;i<map.size();i++){System.out.println(map.get(/*keyname here, maybe map.get(i) or something*/));}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON object (containing `"glossary"`) is more complex than a `Map`. An example of a JSON Object that could be converted to a Java `Map<String, String>` would be:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
```

However, in the example JSON object, there is a string key whose value is JSON object, not a `String`, which does not convert to `Map<String, String>`:

```
{"key": {"anotherKey": "some value"}}
```

There is an example from the Gson homepage [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java). To properly de-serialize your example, you will have to use a combination of `JsonParser` and `Gson`. For example,

```
String jsonObject = "your example";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(jsonObject).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject glossary = obj.get("glossary");
```

etc...

Comment: Wow, thank you!  That was exactly what I was looking for I just didn't quite know how to ask it.  Thank you very much!